# Different theme menu

Tags: plugins, themes

I am trying to use a menu style from a different theme on my WP site.

For example, I currently have 2018 theme installed as my theme, however I want the menu style and capabilities of Divi and keep my styles in the body of the page. So basically just want the header settings of divi to be displayed with all my content that I already built using 2018, this will apply to all pages.

Anybody have any idea if this would be possible to achieve?

Comment: Not possible. You cannot really do it, what u can do is, if you are familiar with CSS and HTML, then Make a child theme, and then build it in header.php So are u willing to use child theme and all? I see you are a new Contributor, so just asking to make sure, you will be able to do things the way I tell you in the answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I am willing to use a child theme. If you could advise how this could be achieved, that'll be great. I basically need an overlay menu with second level menu items

Comment: Thats fairly advanced use case, asking you again do u have knowledge of PHP, HTML, and CSS, and also, is that you just want the looks of it, or do u want some backend functionality also? doing what u want would mean that you would not be able to add new menu items from wp-admin, and slightest changes would also need code, I have exact thing which you want implemented on my site, I am using my custom theme, but navbar design is of Neve theme

Comment: And I with experience can tell, shifting and building that custom navbar was a mess of code, u sure you can code, if not I recommend u to either leabe the idea, or hire a WordPress Developer